# How to get the time from a text document and subtract the current time from it

Tags: python, datetime

I have a text file with the following structure:  (city, arrival time, departure time )

```
New-York      14:40    8:00
Los-Angeles   12:00   17:00
San-Diego     14:15    7:10
```

I find the city I want, and then I need to get the arrival time and the departure time. I can't get the departure time

```
hours_arrival = re.compile(r''+city+'.*?([0-9]+)')
min_arrival = re.compile(r''+city+'.*?([0-9]+ +)')
hours_departure =
min_departure =

with open('base.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match =hours_arrival.match(line)
        if match:
            hs = int(match.group(1))
        match = min_arrival.match(line)
        if match:
            ms = int(match.group(1))
```

Then subtract the arrival time from the current_time and compare it to <= 1 hour
and get only the number of minutes. I get an error. I can't figure out how to subtract from the current time.

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
t4 = timedelta(hours=hs, minutes=ms)
t5 = timedelta(hours=1, minutes=00)

min = t4 - current_time

if min <= t5:
    print(min)  
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: You can use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). If delimiter between columns is tab use `delimiter="\t"`, if it's multiple spaces use `delimiter=" "` and `skipinitialspace=True`. It'll be good alternative to regular expressions.

Comment: In row with `Los-Angeles` departure time is `17:00`, arrival time is `12:00`, what result are you expecting to get? -300 minutes *(5 hours)*? +1140 minutes *(19 hours)*?

Comment: If the value obtained after subtraction is less than or equal to one hour, then the minutes should be output, if more, then there is no need to output anything :)

Comment: In the Los Angeles example, I need to subtract 12:00 from the time that is now. (Which is now on my watch.)

Comment: current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time() with this you create Time object. Time object supports only comparison. You have to create datetime object with the desired time, then you can subtract timedelta from it. 
More explanation can be find here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70820497/10824407#comment125199703_70820497) comment it'll be better to use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read table-like file. It's not clear what divider used in this file. It could be either tab (`\t`) or multiple spaces. So to read file and split each row by columns you can use next code:

```py
import csv

with open('base.txt') as f:
    # if columns divided by '\t'
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    # if columns divided by spaces
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

To find current time you can use [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and to parse time string you can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with `%H:%M` format. Also you will need to set `year`, `month` and `day` to current date in parsed `datetime` object which can be done using [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace). Code:

```py
from datetime import datetime

arrival = '12:00'
now = datetime.now()
arrival_time = datetime.strptime(arrival, '%H:%M').\
    replace(now.year, now.month, now.day)
difference = now - arrival_time
if 0 <= difference.total_seconds() <= 3600:
    print(difference)
else:
    print('no')
```

So combining two code samples above you can get next code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('base.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        try:
            arrival_time = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M')
            departure_time = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%H:%M')
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            pass
        else:
            now = datetime.now()
            arrival_time = arrival_time.replace(now.year, now.month, now.day)
            departure_time = departure_time.replace(now.year, now.month, now.day)
            difference = now - arrival_time
            if 0 <= difference.total_seconds() <= 3600:
                print(difference)
            else:
                print('no')
```

Comment: it's a little unclear how the primary search is done by city?

Comment: @booblik, primary search? There is no search just iterating file line by line splitting rows by columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:
in arrival_time substitute hour and minute with time of arrival

```
    current_time = datetime.now()
    arrival_time = datetime(current_time.year, current_time.month, current_time.day, hour=8, minute=14)
    mm = (current_time - arrival_time).seconds // 60

    if mm <= 60:
        print(mm)  
    else:
        print('no')
```